# Changing a class's html not working

Tags: javascript

I have a function which changes the html of elements with this class (there is actually only 1).

But it is not doing anything and no errors in console...

```
function addRightButton() {
    $('.fc-calendar-right').html = '<p>Hi!</p>';
}
```

What could be wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should call jQuery's `html()` function to change the html of an element(s). like so:

```
function addRightButton() {
    $('.fc-calendar-right').html('<p>Hi!</p>');
}
```

Comment: Please don't just post code, you should also include an explanation of what you changed.

Comment: @Milo are you calling the function?

Comment: Yes, yes I am. :) But maybe the elenent only exists after I call it.

Comment: Please post related HTML source as well

Comment: Is there any way I can make this code run on any new elements created with this class?

Comment: If you want to bind events to elements that aren't in the DOM yet you can use jQuery's 'live()' or (the better) 'on()' methods:

    $('a').live("click", function() { // do something });

see here: http://api.jquery.com/live/